# Unity3D Always capturing input even when not focused when embedded in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, unity-game-engine, input

I currently have a Unity3D program being embedded in a WPF page using a WindowsFormsHost. However, whenever scrolling on the page when not focused on the unity application, the exe still captures that input and does what the Unity exe is supppossed to do. Is there some way to distinguish between what is from when Unity is focused and when it's not?

I've tried looking in the `process` class to see if there was any methods or properties related to focus, to no avail. I've also tried looking in Unity's native classes to check for focus on the application before accepting input, again to no avail.

This is how I'm embedding the application in WPF

```cs
[DllImport("User32.dll")]
        static extern bool MoveWindow(IntPtr handle, int x, int y, int width, int height, bool redraw);

        internal delegate int WindowEnumProc(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lparam);
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        internal static extern bool EnumChildWindows(IntPtr hwnd, WindowEnumProc func, IntPtr lParam);

        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern int SendMessage(IntPtr hWnd, int msg, IntPtr wParam, IntPtr lParam);

        private Process process;
        private IntPtr unityHWND = IntPtr.Zero;

        private const int WM_ACTIVATE = 0x0006;
        private readonly IntPtr WA_ACTIVE = new IntPtr(1);
        private readonly IntPtr WA_INACTIVE = new IntPtr(0);
        private bool hasStartedOnce = false;



        public UnityUserControl()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            try
            {
                StartProgram(this.Panel1.Handle.ToInt32());
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }
        }

        public void StopUnity()
        {
            process.Kill();
            this.Refresh();
        }

        public Int32 GetPanelHandle()
        {
            return this.Panel1.Handle.ToInt32();
        }

        public void StartProgram(Int32 panelHandleInt)
        {
            try
            {
                if (File.Exists("SamMaintenanceRackRobot.exe"))
                {
                    process = new Process();
                    process.StartInfo.FileName = "SamMaintenanceRackRobot.exe";

                    process.StartInfo.Arguments =
                        "-parentHWND " + panelHandleInt + " " + Environment.CommandLine;
                    process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
                    process.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
                    process.Start();


                    process.WaitForInputIdle();

                    Thread.Sleep(1000);
                    EnumChildWindows(Panel1.Handle, WindowEnum, IntPtr.Zero);
                    this.Load += UserControl1_Loaded;

                    hasStartedOnce = true;
                }


        }

        void UserControl1_Loaded(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Window window = Application.Current.MainWindow;
            window.Closing += window_Closing;
        }

        void window_Closing(object sender, global::System.ComponentModel.CancelEventArgs e)
        {
            DeactivateUnityWindow();
        }

        private void ActivateUnityWindow()
        {
            SendMessage(unityHWND, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_ACTIVE, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private void DeactivateUnityWindow()
        {
            SendMessage(unityHWND, WM_ACTIVATE, WA_INACTIVE, IntPtr.Zero);
        }

        private int WindowEnum(IntPtr hwnd, IntPtr lparam)
        {
            unityHWND = hwnd;
            ActivateUnityWindow();
            return 0;
        }

        private void panel1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MoveWindow(unityHWND, 0, 0, Panel1.Width, Panel1.Height, true);
            ActivateUnityWindow();
        }
```